# Why can't enum constructors be protected or public in Java?

Tags: java, enums, constructor

The whole question is in the title. For example:

```
enum enumTest {

        TYPE1(4.5, "string1"), TYPE2(2.79, "string2");
        double num;
        String st;

        enumTest(double num, String st) {
            this.num = num;
            this.st = st;
        }
    }
```

The constructor is fine with the default or `private` modifier, but gives me a compiler error if given the `public` or `protected` modifiers.

Comment: "The constructor is fine with the default or private modifier". Well, yes and no. The default isn't a `package-private` modifier. The default is, in fact, `private`. You can see this by running `javap -p enumTest.class`. Therefore, the constructor is **_always_** private.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Think of Enums as a class with a finite number of instances.  There can never be any different instances beside the ones you initially declare.

Thus, you cannot have a public or protected constructor, because that would allow more instances to be created.

*Note: this is probably not the official reason.  But it makes the most sense for me to think of `enums` this way.*

Comment: It does make a lot of sense. But then why should "default" be allowed? Because then other classes in the same package can invoke the constructor too.

Comment: @Anita, are you sure default is allowed?

Comment: Yeah. I compiled and ran the code sample in the OP. No errors. But the odd thing is I still can't manually call the constructor, even with default. I thought default means as long as you're in the same package, you can access it? Am I missing something big here?

Comment: @Anita See Daniel's answer. "You cannot invoke an enum constructor yourself."

Comment: @Anita, all interface methods are public and abstract ... so in interface Runnable ( void run ( ) ; } the run method is public and abstract.  Perhaps the java designers did the same thing for enum constructors (they are private whether or not you mark them private).

Comment: Actually only private access modifier is allowed for enum constructors. "If no access modifier is specified for the constructor of an enum type, the constructor is private." - JLS http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.3

Comment: All constructors of an enum class are implicitly private, even if the private modifier are omitted.

Comment: I read the docs and yes, it is private by default. But why when I go to documents from my IDE, I see this: `protected Enum(String name, int ordinal)`? Here it says it is protected and not private. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 23):

Because you cannot call the constructor yourself.

Here is what the [tutorials on Enums](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) has to say:

> **Note:** The constructor for an enum type must be package-private or private access. It automatically creates the constants that are defined at the beginning of the enum body. You cannot invoke an enum constructor yourself.

Comment: Taken from the link Daniel provided "Note: The constructor for an enum type must be package-private or private access. It automatically creates the constants that are defined at the beginning of the enum body. You cannot invoke an enum constructor yourself." Since you cannot call it yourself it doesn't matter why it can be package-private.

Comment: But on the other hand, this restriction doesn't really explain *why* we can't have public or protected enum constructors. It's a bit weird and inconsistent to allow two access modifiers out of four; it would make more sense to allow all access modifiers ('cause you still can't call the constructor) or just allow one (best candidates being `private` - to point out that this can't be accessed from elsewhere - or maybe default, to reduce code noise).

Comment: @gustafc: my sentiments exactly!

Answer (score 10):

Enums contain a fixed set of values, which must all be known at compile-time. It doesn't make sense to create new literals at run-time, which would be possible if the constructor were visible.

Answer (score 4):

This is because enum is Java contains fixed constant values. So, there is no point in having public or protected constructor as you cannot create instance of enum.

Also, note that internally enum is converted to class as below.

```
enum Color {
 RED, BLUE, YELLOW;
}
```

This will internally converted to:

```
public final class Color {
 private Color() {}
 public static final Color RED = new Color();
 public static final Color BLUE = new Color();
 public static final Color YELLOW = new Color();
}
```

So, every enum constant is represented as an object of type enum. As we can't create enum objects explicitly hence we can't invoke enum constructor directly.

Answer (score -1):

The key point to  remember is that an enums that is not enclosed in a class can be declared with only the **public** or **default** modifier, just like a non-inner class.

Comment: Again, this question is about enum *constructors*, not the enum types themselves.