# Why can constructors within an enum in Java be declared only private?

Tags: java, constructor, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't enum constructors be protected or public in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664077/why-cant-enum-constructors-be-protected-or-public-in-java)

The following code just demonstrates the use of `enum` in Java. It has nothing to do with and just sums up the values of the members of that `enum`.

```
package enumtest;

enum Sum
{        
    Pen(10),Pencil(15),Eraser(5);

    private int value;

    private Sum(int value)
    {
        this.value=value;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return(value);
    }
}

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        int sum=0;

        for(Sum o:Sum.values())
        {
            sum+=o.getValue();
        }

        System.out.println("sum = "+sum);
    }
}
```

---

It displays `sum = 30` on the console. Just one question here. Generally, in a class, constructors are declared `public` then why can constructors in `enum`  only be declared `private`? The other modifiers `public` and `protected` are not allowed with it. Even declaring it `public` causes a compile-time error. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also declare them without any keyword, e.g. just `Sum(int value)`.

The reason is because Java itself will create the various instances for you, and as Singletons - which is necessary for Enums to work correctly.  `public` or `protected` would imply that or allow additional instances of the same enum to be created by other callers, which would break the Singleton guarantee.

Comment: Hmm but a package protected (no modifier) constructor is fine and we can make basically the same arguments for that one..

Comment: If no access modifier is specified for the constructor of a normal class, the constructor has *default access*. If no access modifier is specified for the constructor of an *enum type*, the constructor is **private**. It is a compile-time error, if the constructor of an *enum type* (§8.9) is declared `public` or `protected`. From [§8.8.3]


  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.8.3 JLS.

Comment: The above is for the Java 6 language spec. In the Java 8 spec, the info on enum constructor visibility is now in [§8.9.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2).