# Is it possible to assign numeric value to an enum in Java?

Tags: java, enums

Is anything like this possible in Java? Can one assign custom numeric values to enum elements in Java?

```
public enum EXIT_CODE {
    A=104, B=203;
}
```

Comment: Not directly as you've written, i.e., where an enum value *equals* a number, but yes indirectly as shown in Ben S's link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can set enum start value in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067352/can-set-enum-start-value-in-java)

Comment: @Benoit I don't think It's a dupe: that one is about setting just the first value and incrementing from there, this is about setting all values. But definitely related.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

```
public enum EXIT_CODE {
    A(104), B(203);

    private int numVal;

    EXIT_CODE(int numVal) {
        this.numVal = numVal;
    }

    public int getNumVal() {
        return numVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use enum constructor in code. `EXIT_CODE.A` and `EXIT_CODE.B` are the only instances that will ever exist.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky in particular, the constructor of an enum cannot be public: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664077/why-cant-enum-constructors-be-protected-or-public-in-java

Comment: will this still work with gson and converting from json.

Comment: You could also declare the variable "public final int numVal" and just access it directly as EXIT_CODE.A.numVal (I prefer the name 'value'), without the need for an accessor method.  Since it's final, it can only be set in the constructor.  IMO it leads to slightly cleaner code, but it's mostly a matter of preference, I suppose.  Using a final variable saves you one method definition.

Comment: that's what is called an enumerated class, I think simple enum and enum class are different things

Answer (score 39):

[**Yes**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), and then some, example from documentation:

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    // in kilograms
    private final double mass;
    // in meters
    private final double radius;
    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    private double mass() { return mass; }
    private double radius() { return radius; }

    // universal gravitational 
    // constant  (m3 kg-1 s-2)
    public static final double G = 6.67300E-11;

    double surfaceGravity() {
        return G * mass / (radius * radius);
    }
    double surfaceWeight(double otherMass) {
        return otherMass * surfaceGravity();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java Planet <earth_weight>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        double earthWeight = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double mass = earthWeight/EARTH.surfaceGravity();
        for (Planet p : Planet.values())
           System.out.printf("Your weight on %s is %f%n",
                             p, p.surfaceWeight(mass));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your public static void main(String[] args) inside of the enum itself??

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky To make the example self-contained I guess!

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: because it is that way in the official docs (follow the **Yes**-link)

Comment: @user1587329 Interesting, I guess that is for testing purposes only.  I don't see a way to use that in production release code...

Answer (score 5):

Extending Bhesh Gurung's answer for assigning values, you can add explicit method to set value

```
   public ExitCode setValue( int value){
      //  A(104), B(203);
      switch(value){
        case 104: return ExitCode.A;
        case 203: return ExitCode.B;
        default:
                   return ExitCode.Unknown //Keep an default or error enum handy
      }
   }
```

From calling application

```
int i = 104; 
ExitCode serverExitCode = ExitCode.setValue(i);
```

//You've valid enum from now

[Unable to comment to his answer, hence posting it separately]

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a way to group constants in a class, you can use a static inner class:

```
public class OuterClass {
    public void exit(boolean isTrue){
        if(isTrue){
            System.exit(ExitCode.A);
        }else{
            System.exit(ExitCode.B);
        }
    }
    public static class ExitCode{
        public static final int A = 203;
        public static final int B = 204;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an older question, but it comes up first in a Google search, and among the excellent answers provided, I didn't see anything fully comprehensive, so I did a little more digging and I ended up writing an enum class that not only allowed me to assign multiple custom values to the enum constants, I even added a method that allows me to assign values to them on the fly during code execution.

This enum class is for a "server" program that I run on a Raspberry Pi. The program receives commands from a client then it executes terminal commands that make adjustments to a webcam that is affixed to my 3D printer.

Using the Linux program 'v4l2-ctl' on the Pi, you can extract all of the possible adjustment commands for a given attached webcam, which also provides the setting datatype, the min and max values, the number of value steps in a given value range etc., so I took all of those and put them in an enum and created an enum interface that makes it easy to both set and get values for each command as well as a simple method to get the actual terminal command that is executed (using the Process and Runtime classes) in order to adjust the setting.

It is a rather large class and I apologize for that, but for me, it's always easier to learn something when I can see it working in full context, so I decided not to scale it down. However, even though it's large, it is definitely simple and it should be obvious what's happening in the class with minimal effort.

```
package constants;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum PICam {
    BRIGHTNESS                  ("brightness",                  0,      "int",      0,      100,    1,  50),
    CONTRAST                    ("contrast",                    1,      "int",      100,    100,    1,  0),
    SATURATION                  ("saturation",                  2,      "int",      100,    100,    1,  0),
    RED_BALANCE                 ("red_balance",                 3,      "intmenu",  1,      7999,   1,  1000),
    BLUE_BALANCE                ("blue_balance",                4,      "int",      1,      7999,   1,  1000),
    HORIZONTAL_FLIP             ("horizontal_flip",             5,      "bool",     0,      1,      1,  0),
    VERTICAL_FLIP               ("vertical_flip",               6,      "bool",     0,      1,      1,  0),
    POWER_LINE_FREQUENCY        ("power_line_frequency",        7,      "menu",     0,      3,      1,  1),
    SHARPNESS                   ("sharpness",                   8,      "int",      100,    100,    1,  0),
    COLOR_EFFECTS               ("color_effects",               9,      "menu",     0,      15,     1,  0),
    ROTATE                      ("rotate",                      10,     "int",      0,      360,    90, 0),
    COLOR_EFFECTS_CBCR          ("color_effects_cbcr",          11,     "int",      0,      65535,  1,  32896),
    VIDEO_BITRATE_MODE          ("video_bitrate_mode",          12,     "menu",     0,      1,      1,  0),
    VIDEO_BITRATE               ("video_bitrate",               13,     "int",      25000,  25000000,   25000,  10000000),
    REPEAT_SEQUENCE_HEADER      ("repeat_sequence_header",      14,     "bool",     0,      1,      1,  0),
    H264_I_FRAME_PERIOD         ("h_264_i_frame_period",        15,     "int",      0,      2147483647,1,   60),
    H264_LEVEL                  ("h_264_level",                 16,     "menu",     0,      11,     1,  11),
    H264_PROFILE                ("h_264_profile",               17,     "menu",     0,      4,      1,  4),
    AUTO_EXPOSURE               ("auto_exposure",               18,     "menu",     0,      3,      1,  0),
    EXPOSURE_TIME_ABSOLUTE      ("exposure_time_absolute",      19,     "int",      1,      10000,  1,  1000),
    EXPOSURE_DYNAMIC_FRAMERATE  ("exposure_dynamic_framerate",  20,     "bool",     0,      1,      1,  0),
    AUTO_EXPOSURE_BIAS          ("auto_exposure_bias",          21,     "intmenu",  0,      24,     1,  12),
    WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO_PRESET   ("white_balance_auto_preset",   22,     "menu",     0,      9,      1,  1),
    IMAGE_STABILIZATION         ("image_stabilization",         23,     "bool",     0,      1,      1,  0),
    ISO_SENSITIVITY             ("iso_sensitivity",             24,     "intmenu",  0,      4,      1,  0),
    ISO_SENSITIVITY_AUTO        ("iso_sensitivity_auto",        25,     "menu",     0,      1,      1,  1),
    EXPOSURE_METERING_MODE      ("exposure_metering_mode",      26,     "menu",     0,      2,      1,  0),
    SCENE_MODE                  ("scene_mode",                  27,     "menu",     0,      13,     1,  0),
    COMPRESSION_QUALITY         ("compression_quality",         28,     "int",      1,      100,    1,  30);


    private static final Map<String, PICam>    LABEL_MAP       = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<Integer, PICam>   INDEX_MAP       = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<String, PICam>    TYPE_MAP        = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<Integer, PICam>   MIN_MAP         = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<Integer, PICam>   MAX_MAP         = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<Integer, PICam>   STEP_MAP        = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<Integer, PICam>   DEFAULT_MAP     = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<Integer, Integer> THIS_VALUE_MAP  = new HashMap<>();

    private static final String                baseCommandLine = "/usr/bin/v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-ctrl=";

    static {
        for (PICam e: values()) {
            LABEL_MAP.put(e.label, e);
            INDEX_MAP.put(e.index, e);
            TYPE_MAP.put(e.type, e);
            MIN_MAP.put(e.min, e);
            MAX_MAP.put(e.max, e);
            STEP_MAP.put(e.step, e);
            DEFAULT_MAP.put(e.defaultValue, e);
        }
    }

    public final String label;
    public final int index;
    public final String type;
    public final int min;
    public final int max;
    public final int step;
    public final int defaultValue;

    private PICam(String label, int index, String type, int min, int max, int step, int defaultValue) {
        this.label = label;
        this.index = index;
        this.type = type;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.step = step;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public static void setValue(Integer index, Integer value) {
        if (THIS_VALUE_MAP.containsKey(index)) THIS_VALUE_MAP.replace(index, value);
        else THIS_VALUE_MAP.put(index, value);
    }

    public Integer getValue (Integer index) {
        return THIS_VALUE_MAP.getOrDefault(index, null);
    }

    public static PICam getLabel(String label) {
        return LABEL_MAP.get(label);
    }

    public static PICam getType(String type) {
        return TYPE_MAP.get(type);
    }

    public static PICam getMin(int min) {
        return MIN_MAP.get(min);
    }

    public static PICam getMax(int max) {
        return MAX_MAP.get(max);
    }

    public static PICam getStep(int step) {
        return STEP_MAP.get(step);
    }

    public static PICam getDefault(int defaultValue) {
        return DEFAULT_MAP.get(defaultValue);
    }

    public static String getCommandFor(int index, int newValue) {
        PICam picam = INDEX_MAP.get(index);
        String commandValue = "";
        if ("bool".equals(picam.type)) {
            commandValue = (newValue == 0) ? "false" : "true";
        }
        else {
            commandValue = String.valueOf(newValue);
        }
        return baseCommandLine + INDEX_MAP.get(index).label + "=" + commandValue;
    }

    public static String getCommandFor(PICam picam, Integer newValue) {
        String commandValue = "";
        if ("bool".equals(picam.type)) {
            commandValue = (newValue == 0) ? "false" : "true";
        }
        else {
            commandValue = String.valueOf(newValue);
        }
        return baseCommandLine + INDEX_MAP.get(picam.index).label + "=" + commandValue;
    }

    public static String getCommandFor(PICam piCam) {
        int    newValue     = piCam.defaultValue;
        String commandValue = "";
        if ("bool".equals(piCam.type)) {
            commandValue = (newValue == 0) ? "false" : "true";
        }
        else {
            commandValue = String.valueOf(newValue);
        }
        return baseCommandLine + piCam.label + "=" + commandValue;
    }

    public static String getCommandFor(Integer index) {
        PICam piCam = INDEX_MAP.get(index);
        int    newValue     = piCam.defaultValue;
        String commandValue = "";
        if ("bool".equals(piCam.type)) {
            commandValue = (newValue == 0) ? "false" : "true";
        }
        else {
            commandValue = String.valueOf(newValue);
        }
        return baseCommandLine + piCam.label + "=" + commandValue;
    }
}
```

Here are some ways that the class can be interacted with:

This code:

```
public static void test() {
    PICam.setValue(0,127); //Set brightness to 125
    PICam.setValue(PICam.SHARPNESS,143); //Set sharpness to 125
    String command1 = PICam.getSetCommandStringFor(PICam.BRIGHTNESS); //Get command line string to include the brightness value that we previously set referencing it by enum constant.
    String command2 = PICam.getSetCommandStringFor(0); //Get command line string to include the brightness value that we previously set referencing it by index number.
    String command3 = PICam.getDefaultCamString(PICam.BRIGHTNESS); //Get command line string with the default value
    String command4 = PICam.getSetCommandStringFor(PICam.SHARPNESS); //Get command line string with the sharpness value that we previously set.
    String command5 = PICam.getDefaultCamString(PICam.SHARPNESS); //Get command line string with the default sharpness value.
    System.out.println(command1);
    System.out.println(command2);
    System.out.println(command3);
    System.out.println(command4);
    System.out.println(command5);
}
```

Produces these results:

```
/usr/bin/v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-ctrl=brightness=127
/usr/bin/v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-ctrl=brightness=127
/usr/bin/v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-ctrl=brightness=50
/usr/bin/v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-ctrl=sharpness=143
/usr/bin/v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-ctrl=sharpness=0
```