# How to make key value like enum in java

Tags: java, json, hibernate, enums, alpacajs

I need to make an `Enum` containing some strings with spaces and their values in `int` like:

```
public enum status{
Active(1),
Inactive(2);
}
```

because I am using it with hibernate and also will convert it to JSON for alpaca js forms.

like:

```
[{"text": "Inactive", "value":"2"},{"text": "Active", "value":"1"}]
```

I'm stuck in making `enum`.  how to make such type of `enum`?

Comment: it is not duplicate because i'm using hibernate annotated bean in which it is used so I need key and value with spaces, link you shared is making enum having value as string but its key is not integer it is also string

Comment: Are you sure that enum is the only way to solve this issue?

Comment: The English word ‘inactive’ is spelled with no space in it. Are you quite positive you cannot live with using the correct spelling? :-)

Comment: Thanks but its client requirement and further in future we can face such kind of requirement with such different values.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Hibernate. You **cannot** have spaces in an enum value, that is forbidden by the Java language itself. You will have to find another solution to the use case you didn't describe.

Comment: You can totally avoid the problem by properly spelling *inactive*

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can not put space between strings. Instead of the you can use underscore as follows:

```
In_Active
```

You can use this way:

```
enum Status {

    ACTIVE("Active", 1), IN_ACTIVE("In Active", 2);

    private final String key;
    private final Integer value;

    Status(String key, Integer value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I know I can't but I need it

Comment: Pls check modified answer.

Comment: Thanks @Chandana Kumara need little more help I've implemented it but the hibernate is getting its name and displaying it.

Comment: Do you try with @Enumerated annotation?

Comment: Refer this:https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html_single/#basic-enums OR https://virgo47.wordpress.com/2014/08/02/converting-java-enums-to-values-and-back/

Comment: This for xml version:https://talk.openmrs.org/t/best-practice-to-store-enum-via-hibernate/1721

Answer (score 11):

You can hold multiple values in one `enum` and even have getters to handle them. Here is an example I used once (I try to adapt it to your problem):

```
public enum Status{

    ACTIVE(1, "Active"),
    INACTIVE(2, "In Active");

    private final Integer value;
    private final String text;

    /**
     * A mapping between the integer code and its corresponding text to facilitate lookup by code.
     */
    private static Map<Integer, Status> valueToTextMapping;

    private Status(Integer value, String text){
        this.value = value;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public static Status getStatus(Integer i){
        if(valueToTextMapping == null){
            initMapping();
        }
        return valueToTextMapping.get(i);
    }

    private static void initMapping(){
        valueToTextMapping = new HashMap<>();
        for(Status s : values()){
            valueToTextMapping.put(s.value, s);
        }
    }

    public Integer getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public String getText(){
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Status");
        sb.append("{value=").append(value);
        sb.append(", text='").append(text).append('\'')
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

So in your code you can simply use `Status.ACTIVE` and it will represent an instance of your Enum, that holds `value` and `text` the way you want it

Comment: Sorry, I am a little too late, didn't see Chandana Kumara's answer

Comment: Great but can you help me out why hibernate auto generated bean having its name as string not its text

Comment: I am not sure to what sort of auto-generation you are referring to, but there is a difference between `Status.ACTIVE.name()` and `Status.ACTIVE.toString()` and with this implementation even `Status.ACTIVE.getText()` It is possible that the auto-generated code calls the `.name()` method. In this case you should change that and call `.getText()` or change your `toString()` (even better)

Comment: in hibernate we use list function which automatically run the select query and make list of bean class fill with those values.

Comment: Sorry, that  I can't help you any further from here. It may be best if you try it out with this "new" enum implementation and check what Strings you get. It is very likely that the `.toString()` method is used to convert the enum into  String - so you might want to override that method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a space in the middle of an identifier.

Check out this link [Is it possible to assign numeric value to an enum in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811815/is-it-possible-to-assign-numeric-value-to-an-enum-in-java) for assigning the value to an enum in java.

Comment: thanks but it's value don't have spaces

Comment: Doesn't your enum values are all int type?

Comment: values are all int and text is string