# Understanding the syntax of this enum statement

Tags: kotlin

I came across the following Kotlin code for an enum:

```
enum class Section(val position: Int, val textKey: Int, val fragment: Fragment) {

    GUIDE(0, R.string.main_pager_guide, QotGuideFragment()),
    LEARN(1, R.string.main_pager_learn, QotLearnFragment()),
    ME(2, R.string.main_pager_me, QotToBeVisionFragment()),
    PREPARE(3, R.string.main_pager_prepare, QotPrepareFragment()),
    ;
}
```

However, when I review the Kotlin docs on enums, I don't see anything in it that shows this kind of syntax. The line:

> GUIDE(0, R.string.main_pager_guide, QotGuideFragment())

I don't understand how these 3 parameters are used. Also, the enum class Section shows 3 constructor parameters that don't appear to be used.

The official docs on enum are at:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html

Comment: the Section constructor has 3 params, and the GUIDE() call passes 3 params of matching types, that should ring a bell. The same syntax is used in the 2nd example of the docs you link to, it's just a slighlty simplified version

Comment: So is this considered an anonymous class?

Comment: no, I'm not sure how you came to that conclusion

Comment: **And this is possible in Java too**. An example here -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8811869/816416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html:

> Each enum constant is an object

so `GUIDE` is an instance of `Section` class, meaning an object initialized as

```
GUIDE(0, R.string.main_pager_guide, QotGuideFragment())
```

You can get the values that initialized `GUIDE`, like this:

```
val guidePosition = Section.GUIDE.position
val guideTextKey = Section.GUIDE.textKey
val guideFragment = Section.GUIDE.fragment
```

Comment: "GUIDE is an instance of Section class" is the most important take-away. That isn't exactly how the docs word it. So your explanation is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

usually your enums will be like that

```
enum class Section() {
    GUIDE,
    LEARN,
    ME,
    PREPARE
}
```

without any parameters

but in your example the base constructor of the enum has parameters that are set as properties also

```
enum class Section(**val** position: Int, **val** textKey: Int, **val** fragment: Fragment)
```

with the keyword val in the constructor you set as property of the class

then it has

```
GUIDE(0, R.string.main_pager_guide, QotGuideFragment()),
LEARN(1, R.string.main_pager_learn, QotLearnFragment()),
ME(2, R.string.main_pager_me, QotToBeVisionFragment()),
PREPARE(3, R.string.main_pager_prepare, QotPrepareFragment())
```

so for `GUIDE` 0 -> position, R.string.main_pager_guide -> textKey and QotGuideFragment -> fragment