# user input male or female sex

Tags: java, enums

I want to write a code that will show the user to input either a male or a female when asked to enter the sex. Firstly I created a class called SexeEnum as shown below

```
public enum SexeEnum {
    Male,
    Female
}
```

Then I want to ask the user to choose between the male or the female gender but I don't know how to proceed as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {             
    Utilisateur utilisateur = new Utilisateur();
    Scanner u = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your Name: ");
    utilisateur.setNom(u.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter your Sexe: ");
    System.out.println("1-Male ");
    System.out.println("2-Female ");
    utilisateur.setSexe(u.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: Please stop tagging your Java questions `javascript`. They are unrelated languages.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript

Comment: You can assign numeric values to `enum` members.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to assign numeric value to an enum in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811815/is-it-possible-to-assign-numeric-value-to-an-enum-in-java)

Comment: Another approach is letting the user write "Male" or "Female": [Scanner with Enum, Java](//stackoverflow.com/q/36035763)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```java
import java.util.Scanner; 

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  
    System.out.println("Enter Sex");

    String userName = myObj.nextLine();  
    System.out.println("Sex is: " + userName);  
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jerry Prosper : Reply if this helped.

Comment: thanks @blubber but I wanted the option male and female using the enum

Comment: Do you mean you want it as a list?