# How to specify enum constructor

Tags: java, constructor, enums, scope

At present I have a class called `TestEnum`. In my `main` method I can work with `firstEnum` and `secondEnum` without needing to specify that `firstEnum` belongs to `GroupA` and `secondEnum` belongs to `GroupB` - the code in `TestEnum` sorts this out.

Suppose that either `firstEnum` or `secondEnum` could be associated with any of the three `SubGrouping` `enum`. I want to be able to make this association from within my `main` method. It is clear I can't use the same approach as with `Grouping` since `GroupA` is allocated to `firstEnum` from within `TestEnum`.

```
public enum TestEnum {
    firstEnum (Grouping.GroupA),
    secondEnum (Grouping.GroupB);


    private Grouping group;
    TestEnum(Grouping group) {
        this.group = group;
    } 

    public enum Grouping {
        GroupA, GroupB;
    }
    public enum SubGrouping {
        SubGroup1, SubGroup2, SubGroup3;
    }
}
```

How do I do this? To be more concrete, it would be good to construct an object such as:

`TestEnum enumWithinMainMethod = TestEnum.firstEnum(SubGrouping.SubGroup1)`

The desired behaviour of this instance is that it belongs to both `SubGroup1` as well as `GroupA`. Then from such an instance it would be good to have the functionality, for example:

```
switch(enumWithinMainMethod) {
    case firstEnum:
        // Do something associated with firstEnum
    case secondEnum:
        // Do something associated with secondEnum
    default:
        // ...
}
```

Comment: This exact behaviour is not (to my knowledge) possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't enum constructors be protected or public in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664077/why-cant-enum-constructors-be-protected-or-public-in-java)

Comment: do you mean SAME enum DIFFERENT property ?

Comment: @farmer1992 I agree that was part of my response but then I deleted it because it got a down vote. But yes that would work, only you would need to increase the number of enum values by n^y where is is there amount of groups and y is the amount of subgroups. Or add the subgroup to the group enum. I still feel given the main question this is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Double think before going this approach.   Enum is aimed to be static, constant and with finite set of values.  What you are doing here is making Enum no longer constant (as you are changing/initializing it in runtime).

I believe there are other way to do, for example, review if it is actually required to have the relationship determined in runtime? Can't it be defined in compile-time?  You may also having a TestEnum-to-SubGroup map, instead of dynamically construct the content of TestEnum.

Anyway, although it is not preferable, it is technically possible in Java.

Of course you cannot delay the "construction" of enum until your main() logic, but you can have enum constructed as normal, and change the internal state.

```
// Mind the naming convention
public enum TestEnum {
    FIRST_ENUM(Grouping.GROUP_A),
    SECOND_ENUM (Grouping.GROUP_B);


    private Grouping group;
    private SubGrouping subGrouping;

    TestEnum(Grouping group) {
        this.group = group;
    } 

    public void setSubGrouping(SubGrouping subGrouping) {
        this.subGrouping = subGrouping;
    }

    public enum Grouping {
        GROUP_A, GROUP_B
    }

    public enum SubGrouping {
        SUB_GROUP_1, SUB_GROUP_2, SUB_GROUP_3;
    }
}
```

Then in your `main()`, do something like

```
TestEnum.FIRST_ENUM.setSubGrouping(TestEnum.SubGrouping.SUB_GROUP_1);
TestEnum.SECOND_ENUM.setSubGrouping(TestEnum.SubGrouping.SUB_GROUP_2);
```

By doing so, you can define the subgrouping of your enum in your `main()`

Once again, this is NOT PREFERABLE.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot call `enum` constructors from outside of an `enum`. You could use a class to get this behaviour.

How about something like this? (The generics are not required, but it does open up the `Groupable` class to multiple types of groupings.)

```
public enum Grouping { GroupA, GroupB; }
public enum SubGrouping { SubGroup1, SubGroup2, SubGroup3; }
public class SubGroupable<G extends Enum<G>,S extends Enum<S>> {
    private G mainGroup;
    private S subGroup;
    public Groupable(G group, S subGroup) {
        this.mainGroup = group;
        this.subGroup = subGroup;
    }
    public G getGroup() { return mainGroup; }
    public S getSubGroup() { return subGroup; }
}
```

Usage

```
SubGroupable<Grouping, SubGrouping> g 
        = new SubGroupable<>(Grouping.GroupA, SubGrouping.SubGroup2);
switch (g.getGroup()) {
case Grouping.GroupA: 
    //
    break;
case Grouping.GroupB:
    //
    break;
}
```

You could also create two final groupings:

```
public final Grouping FIRST_GROUP = Grouping.GroupA;
public final Grouping SECOND_GROUP = Grouping.GroupB;
```

This way you can use those constants in your `case` blocks.

```
switch (g.getGroup()) {
case FIRST_GROUPING: // etc
}
```

Comment: How does using a class instead of enum answer the question he asked?

Comment: Did you read the entire question? This is the approximate behaviour he requires.

Comment: Maybe but did you read the question? "How to specify enum constructor". You could edit it if you think that is poorly written.

Comment: Hence my comment on the question, "This exact behaviour is not (to my knowledge) possible." I then offered an alternative that provides very similar behaviour.

Comment: It isn't possible if my answer got a down vote yours does too sorry. You aren't answering the question asked you are inferring a way around the flaw in his logic but the main problem here is he has a problem with his logic. The concept of an Enum does not support this specifically because an enum is immutable (why you can use it with a switch).

Comment: I really don't see where you're going with this. As you just mentioned, Enums do NOT support the behaviour he is requesting. The answer to the question could simply be "nah, you can't do that", or it could be something useful that can be used as an alternative.

Comment: That is the functionality of a forum not stackoverflow. Here if the question is poorly worded you edit it to make it less poorly worded and no matter which way you edit this it is a duplicate question

Comment: (a) The question was not really poorly worded. (b) It is not a duplicate question.