# How to use the "single-element enum type" to make this class a singleton?

Tags: java, enums

I have this class that I use as a singleton this way:

```
FlagOfficer.instance().someVariable
```

Here is the current implementation of the class:

```
public class FlagOfficer {

    public FlagOfficer() {

    }

    static FlagOfficer flagOfficer = null;

    public static FlagOfficer instance() {
        if (flagOfficer == null) {
            flagOfficer = new FlagOfficer();
        }
        return flagOfficer;
    }

    public boolean getLastBackupDate;
    public boolean syncProcessStartedOnce;
}
```

I am right now reading the "Effective Java" book where they say the best way to implement the singleton pattern is to use single-element enum type

Here is an example form the book:

```
public enum Elvis {
    INSTANCE;
    public void leaveTheBuilding() { ... }
}
```

So how do I transform my class so that it uses this pattern? And how do I use it afterwards?

Comment: Is your constructor really public? Anybody can call new FlagOfficer() and you have more than one instance.

Comment: Man, glad you noticed that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public enum FlagOfficer {
    // Enum instances/values should be declared first.
    // Use INSTANCE(arg1, ..) if constructor accepts agruments.
    INSTANCE; 

    // Constructor can accept arguments as well.
    private FlagOfficer() {

    }

    private Date lastBackupDate;
    private boolean syncProcessStartedOnce;

    public Date getLastBackupDate() {
        return lastBackupDate;
    }

    public boolean isSyncProcessStartedOnce() {
        return syncProcessStartedOnce;
    }
 }
```

Usage:

```
FlagOfficer fo = FlagOfficer.INSTANCE;
```

Comment: can I omit the constructor here or should I leave it and leave it private so I avoid instantiation? Can I not create a "fo" object but just do FlagOfficer.INSTANCE.someVariable = true/false instead?

Comment: The constructor can be omitted. Enums can be declared just like classes in Java. So you can certainly make variables inside an enum non-private and access them directly if you wish.

Edit: Enum constructors are implicitly private. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664077/

Comment: You can also add a `public static FlagOfficer instance() { return INSTANCE;}` method to get the feel of a singleton class. This way the consumers of your singleton will still get the FlagOfficer object as before: `FlagOfficer.instance();`.